# Reflow issue when resizing: div size should be updated

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, reflow

I have an odd reflow issue, in Chrome.

When I resize the browser's height, the two divs at the top and bottom of the pink div don't get their width updated, unless I'm doing an ugly timeout workaround where I hide and show the container (I don't like that workaround). This works in FF and Safari, so it's a Chrome bug.

One important requirement is that the pink middle div dictates the size of the parent div because it's a video and I need to show it in full height, without specifying the width.

Is there a way to fix this issue without doing ugly JS workarounds?

HTML:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <div class="header"><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div></div>
  <div class="video">
    <span>1</span>
    <video></video>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.video-wrapper .header,
.video-wrapper .footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.video-wrapper .video{
   height: calc(100% - 16px); 
}

.video-wrapper video {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.video-wrapper span{
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:0;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle with the reproduction: https://jsfiddle.net/7o27qkpx/3/

Answer (score 1):

I think i have understood your requirement and based on that i have edited your Css, please replace this with your css and let me know if this is fine and if yes i will explain the code and if not then can you please clarify your requirement more precisely.

Edited Css :

```
          .video-wrapper{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
            position: relative;
}

.video-wrapper .header,
.video-wrapper .footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.video-wrapper .video{
   height: calc(100% - 16px); 
    width: 100%;
}

.video-wrapper video {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
    width: 100%;
}

.video-wrapper span{
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:0;
}
```

Comment: This works because you used width 100%, while I can't use any width, I want the video's height to control the width, by keeping the appropriate aspect ratio.